# Watir Testing Highcharts with only 1 Path element

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have an issue testing highcharts with watir when the graph has only 1 path element.
when u hover through the line on the graph the coordinate of the path element changes. so how can i loop through the line?
An example demo = http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series

Comment: @justinko I have learned how to loop through each path element to test data, but do u know how to loop when u have only 1 path element? Sorry to ask you again on highcharts. Thanks

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to test, you could extract the data directly from the html or possibly directly from the chart using jQuery.

Comment: @JustinKo i am trying to test the value when u hover on to the points.  How to extract the data directly from the html?

Comment: @JustinKo i spent two day searching and testing. still dont have a way to solve this issue. tried xpath that wont get position of each points. How can i loop through the points? is there way for watir to control the cursor just to move horizontal from right to left on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this could be using the xpath on the graph. Using Firepath add-on on firefox browser, when you move your mouse through the graph you will have different xpaths for each position. Then you could do something like

```
browser.element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='highcharts-0']/svg/g[6]/g[2]/path[2]']").click
```

and pick the value you need. Doing this, you may not have accurate xpath for every position in the graph but it will almost serve your need.

Comment: Ur way does not work and element_by_xpath has been deprecited. to element(:xpath)

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the html to extract the data used to create the chart. This assumes that you are not trying to actually test the chart itself (ie you trust the third-party library and just need the data for some other purpose).

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'date'      

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto 'http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series'
puts b.html
#Get the javascript that contains the data used to generate the chart
data_script = b.scripts.find{ |script| script.html =~ /data/ }.html

#Get the starting date from the script
point_start = /pointStart: Date.UTC\((2006), (0), (01)\)/.match(data_script)
date_start = Date.new(point_start[1].to_i, point_start[2].to_i+1, point_start[3].to_i)

#Get an array of the data values from the script
data_values = data_script.scan(/data: \[(.*?)\]/m)[0][0].gsub(/\s/, '').split(',')

#Create an array of all the dates.
#Assuming we know it is incremented by day (otherwise check the pointInterval)
dates = (date_start .. (date_start+data_values.length-1)).map do |day|
    day.strftime("%b %e, %Y").squeeze(' ')
end

#Combine the dates and values
p dates.zip(data_values)
#=> [["Jan 1, 2006", "0.8446"], ["Jan 2, 2006", "0.8445"], ... , ["Dec 30, 2008", "0.7049"], ["Dec 31, 2008", "0.7095"]]
```